# Error in load data in r software - rmarkdown knit

Tags: r, dataset, load

I am new to R programming, so, please bear with me. I want to run a multi linear regression and do prediction for my sport data.

```
load(sports)
summary (sports)
ls(sports)
attach(sports)
fit = lm(sport_score ~ sport_votes + sports_rating)
summary(fit)

newdata = data.frame( sport_vote = 80, sport_rating = 7.7 , data = sports)

predict(fit, newdata, interval="predict")
```

I have used this code which works well and prints the outputs for me perfectly in the console. But, when I want to knit it it has an error of:

Error in load(sports.rdata) : object 'sports.rdata' not found calls:  ... withcallinghandles -> withvisible - > eval -> eval -> load

Comment: Now running it again it has started giving me error if 
Error in load(sports) : bad 'file' argument

Comment: One of the reasons for never using `attach` is that the error messages become completely uninterpretable. In this case it's entirely a matter of speculation because the is no definiton of `sports`. Perhaps you intended to write `load('sports.rdata')`?

Comment: It gives me the same error of : error in load(sports.rdata) ....

Comment: You are not reading carefully. You would not have gotten that error message if you wrote what I wrote. You failed to notice the quotes.

Comment: I removed the attach and used the load('sports.rdata') is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. If you remove the attach then you will need to use a `data=sports` argument in `lm()`

Comment: @42- it worked perfectly by removing the attach and adding the data = sport at the end of my lm. feel free to write it as an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me: One of the reasons for never using `attach` is that the error messages become completely uninterpretable. In this case it's entirely a matter of speculation because the is no definiton of `sports`. Perhaps you intended to write `load('sports.rdata')`? – 42- 1 hour ago

You: It gives me the same error of : error in load(sports.rdata) .... – Zapata 59 mins ago

Me: You are not reading carefully. You would not have gotten that error message if you wrote what I wrote. You failed to notice the quotes. – 42- 57 mins ago

You: I removed the attach and used the load('sports.rdata') is that what you meant? – Zapata 53 mins ago

Me:   Yes. If you remove the attach then you will need to use a data=sports argument in `lm()`